# How to forward environment variable to CMake in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, cmake, eclipse-cdt

I have a project that is configured via CMake, which I have imported into Eclipse and I can compile without issue.

I would like to check the size of certain files and to do so, I am invoking the defined size utility via Cmake command as follows

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET myTarget
    POST_BUILD
    COMMENT "Unit sizes"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_SIZE_UTIL} "C:/LocalData/Projects/build_dir/debug/apps/myApp/code/CMakeFiles/units.dir/myUnit/src/*.o"
)
```

Above command work fine since I am providing the hard-coded path to the `*.o` files

```
Unit sizes
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   xxxx       x     xx      xx     xxx  C:/LocalData/Projects/build_dir/debug/apps/myApp/code/CMakeFiles/units.dir/myUnit/src/a.o
    xxx       x     xx      xx     xxx  C:/LocalData/Projects/build_dir/debug/apps/myApp/code/CMakeFiles/units.dir/myUnit/src/b.o
```

However, I would like to replace the hardcoded path in the Cmake custom_command by a variable `myPath` defined within Eclipse that contains this path, i.e.`myPath=C:/LocalData/Projects/build_dir/debug/apps/myApp`, thus it would be more flexible.

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET myTarget
    POST_BUILD
    COMMENT "Unit sizes"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_SIZE_UTIL} "${myPath}/code/CMakeFiles/units.dir/myUnit/src/*.o"
)
```

Can I achieve this? If so, how can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You shouldn't use an environment variable... almost certainly you want something like `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}`

Comment: Scratch that, you want `$<TARGET_OBJECTS:...>`. Don't poke around in CMake-internal directories like `CMakeFiles`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use an environment variable for this. It's brittle because a user can forget to set it, and redundant because `$<TARGET_OBJECTS:...>` exists.

Based on seeing `code/CMakeFiles/units.dir` in your code, I'm assuming you have a target named `units` declared somewhere. If this is the case, then the fully correct thing to do is just to have CMake paste in the target objects directly via a generator expression:

```
add_custom_command(
  TARGET myTarget POST_BUILD
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_SIZE_UTIL} "$<TARGET_OBJECTS:units>"
  COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS
)
```

That will list exactly the object files of `units` on the command line as *separate arguments* (`COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS` does that), no matter where they are located on disk. This is definitely better practice than munging around inside `CMakeFiles` directories (whose layouts are technically allowed to change without notice).

Comment: Yes you are right, I have a target called like that, what should I set then in `TARGET_OBJECTS` then?